# How to save username, password securely in Keychain in swift

Tags: swift, keychain

First time I am building iOS application, I got stuck in saving data securely. How to save sensitive data like username and password in keychain

in app I am using `UserDefaults` to store and retrieve like below

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set([unameTextfield.text], forKey: "userName")
 UserDefaults.standard.set([passwordTextfield.text], forKey: "userPassword")
```

for retrieving:

```
  let uName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")
  let uPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userPassword")
```

but I want to save data securely in Keychain, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `UserDefault` is not a good solution when it comes to store sensitive information. `Keychain` is what you need; however, the problem is that keychain native API is not as easy/straighforward as `Userdefault` Api.
So, I think a great solution is to use [KeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper).

First, install it. Make your cocaopod file look like this

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'target_name' do
   pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
end
```

Then, install it from the terminal with `pod install` and import it. (This is from the docs)

```
import SwiftKeychainWrapper    

//Set value
let saveSuccessful: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set("Some String", forKey: "myKey")

//get value
let retrievedString: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "myKey")
```

Comment: i know about `KeychainWrapper `  but i want using keychain.. could you guide me pls

Comment: Why is that not a good solution. It still works on keychain